# Is it possible to enable query logging in Cassandra 3.11?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Specifically, Cassandra 3.11.4?

I don't care about performance as this is not currently a production system (in the fullest sense). So for instance, I don't require FQL's performant features that are available in 4.0, which sound like they may be suitable for logging on production systems.

What I would like is *some* way to do query logging, so I can debug what queries my application is sending to my system (which seem to be incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it’s possible
Enable nodetool settraceprobability 1.0
You can find the query in system_traces.events table

Other option is increasing the logging levels to all and grep “native transport request -Id

Comment: In principle, I think the first option is simplest - thanks! Though I would suggest changing the answer to use ` system_traces.sessions`, e.g. `select parameters from system_traces.sessions;` as that is the query appears in the `sessions` table rather than the `events` table, strangely.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good success with Ericsson's ecAudit plugin.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit

To configure it:

- Download their 3.11 jar, and copy it to your `$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/` dir.
- Reference it from within your `cassandra-env.sh` file:

`JVM_EXTRA_OPTS="$JVM_EXTRA_OPTS -Dcassandra.custom_query_handler_class=com.ericsson.bss.cassandra.ecaudit.handler.AuditQueryHandler"`

- In the `cassandra.yaml`, switch-out the default `CassandraRoleManager` to use theirs:

`role_manager: com.ericsson.bss.cassandra.ecaudit.auth.AuditRoleManager`